# Install Ansible Galaxy role as git repository

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-galaxy

I have a requirements.yml file with the following contents:

```
- src: git@github.com:SomeOrg/SomeRole.git
  scm: git
  version: master
  name: some-role
```

If I run `ansible-galaxy`, the role gets includes in the roles directory as expected. The role ends up being an export of the desired git revision rather than a git repository itself. Is there a way to tell `ansible-galaxy` to pull in the role as git repository?

Composer, the PHP package manager, does this by default. Having the dependencies you pull in being git repositories where applicable makes it a lot easier to make changes to those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; => `ansible-galaxy role install -fgr roles/requirements.yml`

---

This is not really clear IMO in the help message but that is the option you are looking for:

```
$ ansible-galaxy install --help
[...]
  -g, --keep-scm-meta   Use tar instead of the scm archive option when
                        packaging the role.
```

You will probably want to ignore the `meta/.galaxy_install_info` file that galaxy is creating upon import inside the role.

Comment: That worked. Not sure how I missed this since I definitely ran the help command before posting here.

Comment: Happens to the best ;) As explained in my answer, I think the doc is not really clear on this option. And I actually went ove it several times while looking for this solution a while ago until I finally tried it and succeeded.